# how to make a dynamic router with parameters in vaadin router

Tags: vaadin, lit-element

I have the following address http://localhost:3000/script?company=1

How to display the required component at this address? What's wrog with me code?

```
   {
            path: '/script?company=:companyId',
            component: 'script-page',
            action: (context, commands) => this.protectedRouter(context, commands)
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the format `/script?company=:companyId` is wrong. The correct format should be like the following (assuming the companyId is required parameter)

```
{
    path: '/script/:companyId',
    component: 'script-page',
    action: (context, commands) => this.protectedRouter(context, commands)
},
```

See the Vaadin (Fusion) [Router documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/fusion/routing/url-parameters) for more details and examples how to use optional and wildcard URL parameters.